# E-commerce webshop: convenience versus flexibility

Tags: web-development, web-services, cloud-service, ecommerce, saas

I would like to build a small ecommerce webshop for a friend, as a learning by experience project for myself. Having done a fair amount of research I am not sure about how to set up the thing. Basically there seems to be a trade-off between convenience, flexibility and learning new things.

Information to consider:

- I'm a data scientists, with some experience in software engineering. I'm also quite familiar with cloud services (mostly AWS). I would like to avoid frustrating tasks in UI's as much as possible.
- We do have a static website (blog) with quite some traffic already. It will be a one-product webshop, which we could host at a subdomain. Furthermore I would also like to use some data science techniques to attract new customers.

It seems like Shopify is very convenient as it allows to quickly build a an e-commerce. However, it doesn't seem so attractive in terms of learning experience.

What other (code-able) options are there around? Would it, for example, be possible to build a serverless ecommerce with AWS services? Or would such solution require some advanced engineering for payment services?

What kind of tools/templates/workflow would you recommend?